# log4net is not writing any messages to the log file or the console

Tags: c#, console-application, log4net

So, I have a console app.

Using log4net to log messages.

Below is my log4net.config file.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<log4net>
    <appender name="FileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender">
        <file value="log.txt" />
        <appendToFile value="true" />
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger - %message%newline" />
        </layout>
    </appender>
    <appender name="ConsoleAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ColoredConsoleAppender">
        <mapping>
            <level value="ERROR" />
            <backColor value="Red, HighIntensity" />
        </mapping>
        <mapping>
            <level value="WARN" />
            <foreColor value="White" />
            <backColor value="Yellow" />
        </mapping>
        <mapping>
            <level value="INFO" />
            <foreColor value="White" />
        </mapping>
        <mapping>
            <level value="DEBUG" />
            <backColor value="Green" />
        </mapping>
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger - %message%newline" />
        </layout>
    </appender>
    <root>
        <level value="ALL" />
        <appender-ref ref="ConsoleAppender" />
        <appender-ref ref="FileAppender" />
    </root>
</log4net>
```

And in my console app I have this class to run

```
public class SchedulerService
{
    private static readonly ILog _log = LogManager.GetLogger(typeof(SchedulerService));
    private readonly SchedulerRegistry _registry;

    public SchedulerService(SchedulerRegistry schedulerRegistry)
    {
        _registry = schedulerRegistry;
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        JobManager.Initialize(_registry);
        JobManager.JobException += JobManager_JobException;
        _log.Info("SchedulerService is started");
    }

    private void JobManager_JobException(JobExceptionInfo info)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("An error just happened with a scheduled job: " + info.Exception);
        _log.Error("An error just happened with a scheduled job: " + info.Exception);
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("SchedulerService is stopped");
    }
}
```

As a result log.txt file is created but its size is zero, its empty, nothing is logged into that files and nothing is logged to console.

**What am I doing wrong?**

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I do not remember "ALL" as a valid log level.  Try "DEBUG" and see if that gets it.

Comment: How are you configuring log4net (i.e. where are you telling it to load the config file)? It would help if you'd include a [mcve] which just configures log4net and logs a message - there's no need for all the job manager code there. Also, are you calling LogManager.Flush at all?

Answer (score 3):

Your `log4net.config` is correct.

Make sure:

1. The `Copy to Output Directory` **property** of the `log4net.config` file is set to `Copy Always`. This is important because you need the config file to be copied to the bin folder when you build and run your application. Do this by right clicking the config file and select `Properties`. Then set the value of the `Copy to Output Directory` property to `Copy Always`.
2. You tell log4net to **load** your config. One way to achieve this is to add the following line to the bottom of your `AssemblyInfo` file:

`[assembly: log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator(ConfigFile = "log4net.config")]`

Comment: I wondered about both of these, but if the log file is being created, that suggests the OP *has* got log4net reading the configuration. Unfortunately without a full example we can run, it's hard to help.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem :)

Looks like its a new feature of VS 2017 that I haven't noticed before.

Previously you could resolve namespace only if you added corresponding components yourself manually via Add Reference or via NuGet Package Manager.

With VS 2017 when you try to resolve a namespace, it actually installs these packages for you. This maybe convenient, but also frustrating, like in my case.

Don't know why but VS decided to include this Common.Logging & Common.Logging.Core packages instead of log4net that was already in my solution.
Probably I trusted blindly and didn't notice that these packages have nothing to do with the library I wanted to use. The weird thing is that the code compiled just fine :)

So that was the reason why the code wasn't working. Be aware.

Answer (score 0):

Try this method. You have to name it ColoredConsoleAppender instead of ConsoleAppender.Hope it works.

```
<appender name="FileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender">
    <file value="log.txt" />
    <appendToFile value="true" />
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger - %message%newline" />
    </layout>
</appender>
<appender name="ColoredConsoleAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ColoredConsoleAppender">
    <mapping>
        <level value="ERROR"/>
        <foreColor value="Red"/>
    </mapping>
    <mapping>
        <level value="INFO"/>
        <foreColor value="White"/>
    </mapping>
    <mapping>
        <level value="DEBUG"/>
        <foreColor value="Green"/>
    </mapping>
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%message%newline"/>
    </layout>
</appender>
<appender name="ConsoleAppender" type="log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender">
    <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%date %-5level %logger - %message%newline"/>
    </layout>
</appender>
<root>
    <priority value="ALL"/>
    <appender-ref ref="FileAppender"/>
    <appender-ref ref="ColoredConsoleAppender"/>


</root>
```